# Active cflayoutarea element not loading source content

Tags: coldfusion

We have a CF 9 project that got upgraded to CF 2016 couple of weeks back. Original developers and the person who upgraded the project left our company. No one in our company ever worked with ColdFusion. So I was asked to do some research in fixing couple of bugs.

Whenever user clicks on different cflayout tabs, source content is getting disappeared after fraction of seconds. If I validate the page source code using IE developer tools, these tabs markup  (markup generated by the tab sourceurl)already exists in the markup. But something is stopping this markup from appearing in UI. Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

P.S: First tab (test1) data is always appearing as expected. Other tabs content is always getting disappeared after some time.

Source code is as follows:

```
<cflayout type="tab" >
<cflayoutarea title="Test1">
    <cfinclude template="./grids/test1Grid.cfm">
</cflayoutarea>
<cfif valuationRuns.recordCount gt 0>
    <cfif StructKeyExists(URL,'ID')>
            <cfset variables.ID = '&ID='&URL.ID>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset variables.ID = ''>
    </cfif>
    <cflayoutarea title="Valuation Summary" source="./valuations.cfm?test_record_id=#testId#&test_name=#URLEncodedFormat(test_name)#&runId=summary" 
                       refreshonactivate="true" overflow="hidden" style="height:570px;" ></cflayoutarea>
    <cfloop query="valuationRuns">
        <cfset RunID = valuationRuns.RunId[currentrow]>
        <cfset RunName = valuationRuns.RunName[currentrow]>
        <cflayoutarea title="Run #valuationRuns.RunId[currentrow]##IIF(Left(valuationRuns.RunName[currentrow],5) NEQ 'RunID',DE(' - #valuationRuns.RunName[currentrow]#'),DE(''))#" source="./valuations.cfm?test_record_id=#testId#&test_name=#URLEncodedFormat(test_name)#&runId=#RunId#&runName=#URLEncodedFormat(RunName)##IIF(StructKeyExists(URL,'ID'),DE('#variables.ID#'),DE(''))#" 
                       refreshonactivate="true" overflow="hidden" style="height:570px;" ></cflayoutarea>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```